# Practice program for home

Tags: exercise, home-exercise

My work make me stay on a desk along time and that make me usually very lazy ,
so is there any recommended practice program to do it at home ?

Comment: What do you mean by “Practice Program”?

Comment: Different people like different things. Most people i know enjoy relatively short workouts (under 1 hour) that make you sweat and hurt and mostly train your abs - most people think that's what a good workout is. Others are obsessed with effectiveness and efficiency and do 5 heavy sets if squads and then take a 5 minute break because study x. Others enjoy activities that they see some deeper meaning in like team sports, variations of rock climbing or such. Some people are competitive, some are not. Is there any best way? Ask a powerlifter or a tennis enthusiast - completely different answers

Answer (score 1):

If you have no weights and are just wanting to stay healthy at home without going to the gym I recommend doing the basic pushups, situps, burpees, mountain climbers and star jumps.

Simple exercises like these done correctly do a degree of intensity can be very good to get your heart pumping and to incorporate your recommended 30 minutes a day of exercise.